# Drag and Drop JLabel scrolling bug

Tags: java, swing

I have a bug in some code that hopefully someone can assist me with. So I have a drag and drop panel whereby the top part of the panel is the draggable target (JTable) and the bottom part is a list of available files (JTable). If the number of files in the list exceeds a certain amount so that the user has to scroll to get to the top (and to the draggable target), if they try to drag a file from the bottom of the list it does not allow the user to scroll to the target area.

Basically, the panel is made up of **2 JTables** separated by a **JLabel** (just a thick black line). Once the user reaches this JLabel it does not scroll up any further. **Is there a way of allowing the ScrollPanel to continue scrolling once the JLabel is reached??**

Code is literally just:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("insets 0, wrap 1", "[grow]"));
JPanel listsPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("insets 0, wrap 1","[grow]","[]0[5:5:5]0[]")); 
JLabel separatorLabel = new JLabel("_");

listsPanel.add(activeHouseStylesTable, "growx");

separatorLabel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 300));
separatorLabel.setAutoscrolls(true);

listsPanel.add(separatorLabel, "growx");
listsPanel.add(inactiveHousestylesTable, "growx");
setupDragAndDrop();

panel.add(listsPanel, "growx");
```

Thanks,

Comment: Certainly - there always is :-) Or in other words: most probably something wrong in the code you are not showing. No way to help without an SSCCE.

Comment: that's code, but not an SSCCE (google if you don't know the term - or look at any comment by @Andrew Thompson, he always provides a link :-)

Comment: @user1065547 A nice attempt, but not good enough since it does not even compile. So add a main method, make the necessary components visible, add some imports so we only have to copy-paste the code in our IDE and press run

Comment: You can attach a mouse listener to the component in the background and listen for drags. Then when you a drag registers, grab the model of the scrollbar and alter is as required.

Comment: Theres going to be a hell of alot of code if I do that as i need to set up the drag and drop. My question basically is are there limitations when using drag and drop? E.g. if I have a JScrollPanel should it just contain one component? I am using 3 and am getting problems so any advice much appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't reproduce the problem: the code snippet below is a slightly adjusted version of yours, the upper table being a dragSource, the lower faking to be a dropTarget. Add the panel to any toplevel window and size it so that only part of the lower is visible. Then start a drag in the upper and move the mouse to the last visible row of the lower: the whole panel scrolls up until you release the mouse.

What's not happening by default (and might be the perceived problem, don' know from your description) is any scrolling *to* the dropTarget: size the frame such that the separator is barely visible, start a drag and move to the lower boundary of the visible content: no scrolling because the visible part is not a valid droplocation anyway so the internal autoscroll not triggered.

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("insets 0, wrap 1", "[grow]"));
    JPanel listsPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("insets 0, wrap 1",
            "[grow]", "[]0[5:5:5]0[]"));
    JLabel separatorLabel = new JLabel("_");
    separatorLabel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 300));

    JTable upper = new JTable(20, 3);
    JTable lower = new JTable(20, 3);
    // enable drag in upper
    upper.setDragEnabled(true);
    TransferHandler tableTransfer = new TransferHandler() {
        @Override
        public boolean canImport(JComponent comp,
                DataFlavor[] transferFlavors) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    lower.setTransferHandler(tableTransfer);

    listsPanel.add(upper, "growx");
    listsPanel.add(separatorLabel, "growx");
    listsPanel.add(lower, "growx");
    panel.add(listsPanel, "growx");
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just a little confused. Are you saying make the bottom JTable not visible?

Comment: no - just saying _if_ the target (in this example it's the lower) is in the same scrollPane but not visible, _then_ it will not scroll. Anyway, snippets are for running, so go ahead, follow the description in the first paragraph and you'll see the working :-)

Comment: Ok yeh so thats the problem that im seeing, how can I overcome this? E.g. "no scrolling because the visible part is not a valid droplocation anyway so the internal autoscroll not triggered." - is there a work around??

Comment: force at least one line of target to be visible on starting the drag, probably in your TransferHandler